# Why do `set shm+=s` and `cno <silent> <cr> <cr>` make Vim display a search command, when the pattern has no match in the current buffer?

Tags: vim

If I start Vim with a minimum of initializations:

```
vim -Nu NONE /path/to/a/file
```

Then execute the following 2 commands:

```
set shm+=s
cno <silent> <cr> <cr>
```

And finally search for a pattern which has no match in the current buffer:

```
/pattern_with_no_match
```

Vim displays the error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: pattern_with_no_match
```

... which is expected. But Vim also displays a line showing the literal search command. Because of this, in total, Vim displays 2 lines + a prompt:

```
/pattern_with_no_match
E486: Pattern not found: pattern_with_no_match
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Instead of just one line with no prompt:

```
E486: Pattern not found: pattern_with_no_match
```

If I remove the `s` flag from the `'shortmess'` option:

```
set shm-=s
```

Or if I remove the `<silent>` argument in the mapping:

```
cno <cr> <cr>
```

Vim displays only 1 line again:

```
E486: Pattern not found: pattern_with_no_match
```

Adding the `s` flag to `'shortmess'` suppresses the messages such as:

```
search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP
```

And the `<silent>` argument passed to the `:cnoremap` command should prevent the mapping from being echoed on the command line.

None of these settings should make Vim more verbose.
So, why does the combination of the setting `set shm+=s` and the mapping `cno <silent> <cr> <cr>`, makes Vim display a search command, when the pattern has no match in the current buffer?

---

It may be a known issue, because I've just found a [comment](https://github.com/google/vim-searchindex/blob/28c509b9a6704620320ef74b902c064df61b731f/plugin/searchindex.vim#L72-L73) inside a plugin which seems related:

```
" NOTE: This cannot use <silent> - it would break cmdline refresh in some
" cases (e.g. multiline commands, <C-R>= usage).
```

But I can't find the relevant section in the help which describes it.

There's this line in `:h map-<silent>`:

```
Using "<silent>" for an abbreviation is possible, but will cause redrawing of the command line to fail.
```

But it's about abbreviations not mappings. Maybe the 2 are linked though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has some built-in logic to determine whether a user message has been shown and can be discarded. Only when there are more messages at once, the *hit-enter prompt* will occur. By silencing the `<CR>` in the command-line, you disrupt this logic; `<silent>` means no output (by the mapping), but the command-line is still open and contains the typed search. Normally, the *search wrap message* would then clear the command-line, but with your `'shm'` setting, you're disabling that, too. Therefore, with the combination of both, you see this effect.

I'm deliberately fuzzy in my explanation because most of this is a side effect of the implementation, and not formally specified. `cno <silent> <cr> <cr>` doesn't make sense. If you have a real-world use case where this is causing problems, please post details about that. In general, hooking into keys that change modes (like `<CR>` and `<Esc>`) is a bad idea and should be avoided.